# rd, rmdir, del what to use

Tags: del, rmdir, rd

Situation:

```
x:\neededmap\files.txt
x:\neededmap\trashmap1\files.txt
x:\neededmap\trashmap1\trashmap2\files.txt
x:\neededmap\trashmap3\files.txt
x:\neededmap\trashmap4\files.txt
```

How to delete by batch all Files.txt and all trashmaps
Or better, just the neededmap must remain.

Answer (score 0):

You may do this through `del /f /s /q files.txt` - this will delete all `files.txt` from the current working directory (CWD) and all subsequent directories. Please use caution.

Microsoft provides excellent documentation on their [Del](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/del) references page. The `/f` forces deletion of read-only files, the `/s` is equivalent to -recurse in Powershell. The `/q` makes it execute quietly and not request for confirmation.